# how can I include python IDE in my application

Tags: python, compiler-construction, ide, desktop-application

I am building a desktop app in python, and I wanted to include a section where the user can write and run python code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOvefflow. Please add an example of your code and specify the question. Your question is too broad now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python scripting to open python idle from the python script using code like this.

```
# importing the module
import os
  
# setting the path of the IDE
# use of \\ is important because 
# \ will be treated as a escape sequence
# here we are using the Python Idle 
# path to open the Python idle
path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python\\python3.7.exe"
  
# using the os.startfile() method
os.startfile(path)
```

In order to add the idle to your application, you can resize the window and place it within your application.